# practise resources for basic sorting

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have to prepare for a midterm and I am looking for a resource where I can practise the three basic sorting algorithms **insertion sort, bubble sort and selection sort** a little.

Last year they had to sort an array with n elements and the elements were integers with values between 0 and m-1 and the complexity had to be of O(n+m).

I did not find any good resources as most of them **deal with more advanced topics** and prepare you for interviews.

So I would be glad if someone could give me a good hint.

Comment: Are you aware that **counting sort** should have been used last year?

Comment: no...we had to come up with the counting sort algorithm by our own.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "practice sorting"? Sets of data to sort by hand? Just whip something up with a random number generator. Examples showing how the methods work? At least Wikipedia has detailed algorithms with pretty animations, or search for "algorithm animation", it is quite popular.

Comment: i mean by that sorting practise problems where you have to implement one of the above mentioned sorting algorithms in an exam-like way.